# How to Scroll a webpage by clicking and Dragging on the Body like touch Device

Tags: jquery, html, touch

Is it possible to scroll a website by holding mouse button down and Dragging vertically or horizontally on the body ( like touch devices ipad). Is there any way to implement this please guide me.

Thank You

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could try [overscroll](https://github.com/azoff/overscroll) plugin.

And [here](http://www.google.fi/search?hl=fi&q=jquery+drag+scroll) you can find more examples...

Comment: Thank You for great plugin. If links or text is present will it work.

Answer (score 5):

I came across this method, courtesy of [this codepen](http://codepen.io/JTParrett/pen/rkofB/) (It's pure JS, but has some flaws)

I've rewritten it with JQuery and edited it to fix the browser issues (Scroll distances retrieved from `document` not `body`), and included a `preventDefault` as this fixes an issue where the dragging occasionally continued after the mouse is released.

```js
var curYPos = 0;
var curXPos = 0;
var curDown = false;

$(document).on("mousemove", function (event) {
  if (curDown === true) {
    $(document).scrollTop(parseInt($(document).scrollTop() + (curYPos - event.pageY)));
    $(document).scrollLeft(parseInt($(document).scrollLeft() + (curXPos - event.pageX)));
  }
});

$(document).on("mousedown", function (e) { curDown = true; curYPos = e.pageY; curXPos = e.pageX; e.preventDefault(); });
$(window).on("mouseup", function (e) { curDown = false; });
$(window).on("mouseout", function (e) { curDown = false; });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/10/1000/800" />
```

Pure JS original (Quite broken, but included for reference):

```js
var curYPos = 0,
  curXPos = 0,
  curDown = false;

window.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
  if (curDown === true) {
    window.scrollTo(document.body.scrollLeft + (curXPos - e.pageX), document.body.scrollTop + (curYPos - e.pageY));
  }
});

window.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
  curDown = true;
  curYPos = e.pageY;
  curXPos = e.pageX;
});
window.addEventListener('mouseup', function(e) {
  curDown = false;
});
```

```html
<img src="https://picsum.photos/id/10/1000/800" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the code - it definitely did the trick! I noticed that the dragscrolling is however a little spastic. Any ideas on how to smooth it out?

Comment: @svershin Are you using my modified version or the original pure JS version? (The original is broken, but included for reference. I've modified the answer to make my suggestions clearer)